# Bind ComboBox Box items to SelectedItem of another Combobox

Tags: .net, silverlight, caliburn.micro

I have two combo boxes.  The first one, Companys has a collection of Company objects.  Each object has a string Name and string collection:

Here is the class:

```
public class clsCompany : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BindableCollection<string> Regions;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Here is the code. The TextBox updates just fine when I select an item.  But the ComboBox which should show the regions does not:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Companys" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Width="100"/>
<ComboBox  x:Name="SelectedCompany_Regions" Width="100"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="SelectedCompany_Name" Width="100" />
```

The only way I can get the 2nd ComboBox to work is to create a new property on my ViewModel which is associated with SelectedCompany.Regions  But why does what I have not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is caused by missing property changed notifications. When you update the Company you also need to raise a property changed notification for that companies Regions so that the regions `ComboBox` is aware its source has also updated. You can achieve this by changing the Companies and SelectedCompany properties to the following:

```
public BindableCollection<Company> Companys { get; set; }
private Company _selectedCompany;
public Company SelectedCompany
{
    get { return _selectedCompany; }
    set
    {
        _selectedCompany = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedCompany);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedCompany.Regions);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did exactly this, but still no update to the SelectedCompany_Regions  combobox.

Comment: @Daniel Hmmmmm...heres a sample application that works for this situation as I understand it...https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B29ZkEHowpX0MGQ5M2U4NTItODNiMC00ZWM0LWE1ZTAtNWRjZGM5YTU5Njgx&hl=en_US&authkey=CPLW6tsH

Comment: Thank you- my Regions was a field, not a property, in the Company class.  That was the issue.

Comment: ah yes, the ViewModelBinder only searches properties

Answer (score 0):

If you make Companys a CollectionView then you should be able to bind the second combo to Companys.CurrentItem.Regions.

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question. A code sample may be helpful.

Comment: Companys is a BindableCollection - what is a CollectionView?